# Creating objects inside a C++ library (like std::cout)

Tags: c++, c++11

I recently read somewhere that `std::cout` is an instance of the `std::ostream` class. I wish to implement a similar kind of thing. I make a class `Animal` and want to provide an instance of `Animal` class `dog` in the library itself like `std::cout`. I am not sure how to do it but here's a code snippet which hopefully will give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
// lib.h

#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

#include <string>

class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    std::string name;
};

Animal dog;
dog.name = "dog";
extern Animal dog;

#endif
```

---

```
// lib.cpp

#include "lib.h"

Animal::Animal() {}

Animal dog;
dog.name = "dog";
```

---

```
// main.cpp

#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Animal my_dog = dog;
    std::cout << my_dog.name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error I get when I try this code:

```
lib.cpp:6:1: error: ‘dog’ does not name a type
 dog.name = "dog";
```

This kind of code may seem silly, but I still am looking for ways to implement this approach and not its alternatives.

**EDIT**:
After several answers which are suggesting using inheritance or including the parameters in constructor. I will explain the actual problem that I am dealing with.

I am working on a motion planning library. The library has an object called `RoadmapPlanner`. It is something similar to what is shown below

```
class RoadmapPlanner {
private:
    Graph g;
public:
    std::function<Graph(Workspace)> build_graph;
    std::function<Path(Graph,Point,Point) find_path;
    // and several others
}
```

Now I want to provide some pre-built motion planners to the user. For example: I want to provide the `voronoi_planner`, which I want to implement by using the following syntax:

```
RoadmapPlanner voronoi_planner;
voronoi_planner.build_graph = voronoi_graph_builder; // this describes what algorithms
voronoi_planner.graph_search = a_star_search;        // will be used internally
voronoi_planner.load_map("map_001.png");
voronoi_planner.run();
```

and so on...
`voronoi_graph_builder`, `a_star_search` etc are functions that I have already written. This thing works perfectly when I do this in the main function. I want to provide several pre-built planners and also allow the user to build planner themselves by using the above syntax. The pre-built planners must be a part of the library so the user can use them by following the below syntax:

```
RoadmapPlanner my_planner = voronoi_planner;
my_planner.search = rrt_search;
```

I hope this explains what I intend to do.

Comment: You can't just assign instance members like that. That belongs in a function (ideally a constructor-provided argument).

Comment: @WhozCraig these are not the actual files, they are just to give an idea of what I'm trying to do. I will change them to the actual files that I am using

Comment: The latter sentence goes directly to your problem. That assignment statement cannot be there. The compiler encountered `dog` and things it is a type (which it isn't, but that is what should be there).

Comment: Do you really want to load a default map and run the planner on it for each of your "pre-built" planners? If you have a lot of pre-built planner, this may slow down your initialization time, which may not be what you want... (especially if you are not using most of the pre-built planners).

Comment: @Holt No, this is what I am doing in the main file, To create the planner only first 2 lines are needed

Comment: @LakshayGarg Then I don't see the problem of including parameters in the constructor? Even if you are not using all the parameters, you could simply have default values for most of them...

Comment: @Holt, I agree, there is no problem in passing parameters in the constructor but that will require you to remember the order in which they need to be passed (you are seeing only 2 parameters but there can be several others). Also consider the case when the user wants to slightly tweak the `voronoi_planner` by changing only the `graph_search` function. I that case the user would need to construct the entire thing again. I will be doing the constructor thing if I don't find a solution but having what I described above would be great

Comment: @LakshayGarg If you only set some attributes when creating the planner, what are the use of the others? Looking at your code, it looks like you could have multiple constructors building various planner (e.g. one setting only `build_graph` and `graph_search`). If you are only using a subset of the attributes at once, you probably have a design flaw.

Comment: @Holt, other parameters have a default value which have been defined in the `RoadmapPlanner` class.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do the assignment of `dog.name` outside any function, you need to construct your `Animal` with its `name` directly:

```
// lib.hpp

class Animal {
public:
    Animal(std::string);
    std::string name;
};

extern Animal dog;

// lib.cpp

Animal::Animal(std::string name) : name(name) {}

Animal dog("dog");
```

If your type meets the requirements for [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), you can omit the constructor:

```
// lib.hpp

class Animal {
public:
    std::string name;
};

extern Animal dog;

// lib.cpp

Animal dog = {"dog"};
```

**Update after your edit:**

In your edit, you define the variable `dog` in both `lib.cpp` and `lib.hpp`, this cannot work per the *one definition rule*: `dog` will be define in each of the `.cpp` file which include `lib.hpp` (and thus will be define multiple times).

If you want to declare `dog` in your `lib.hpp`, you should use an *anonymous namespace* and not define it in `lib.cpp`.

Comment: But that means that I need to include all the parameters that I want to be set in the constructor itself. In my case, I have several parameters of which I want to set only a few and leave others for the user to set.

Comment: @LakshayGarg You can create a constructor with only the parameters you want to set and let the other unset.

Comment: I have made edits to my question, please suggest some measures to deal with the problem explained. Regards

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not allow statements to be placed in the global scope. The simplest way to solve this is to make Animal take its name in in its constructor so you can init your dog like so:

```
Animal dog("dog");
```

Also consider placing your static instance inside the Animal class itself, this way you get the added benefit of proper scope names.

```
// .h

class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    std::string name;
    static Animal dog;
};

// .cpp
Animal Animal::dog("dog");
```

Comment: I have made edits to my problem, please suggest how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;

struct init_i
{
    init_i()::init_i() { i = 5; }
};

init_i _init;
```

i will be set to 5 before main()

Answer (score -1):

What your looking for is class inheritance. In your case it would look like this:

```
// lib.h

class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    std::string name;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    Dog();
};

// lib.cpp

Animal::Animal() {}
Dog::Dog() { name = "dog"; }

// main.cpp

#include "lib.h"

int main() {
    Animal my_dog = Dog();
    std::cout << my_dog.name << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want `dog` to be an instance of a class and not the class itself.

Comment: Not really. Dog may not be a proper subtype of Animal at all, imagine for example that you want to model a database of every animal, are you going to create a subtype for each species?

Comment: @LakshayGarg Oh sorry, i didn't get that from your first post.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest  you read about Object Oriented Programming Paradigms (Encapsulation,  Inheritance  Polymorphism)

Encapsulation means you will keep the attributes of your objects hidden from outside the class and use public method to assign or retrieve values from the object.

```
Class Animal // parent class
{
    protected:
        std::string name;
    public:
        void setName(std::string n) { name = n; }
        std::string getName() { return name; }
}
```

Inheritance means allowing an object (child object) to get the same attributes form its parents. In addition you can have additional attributes and methods unique to the child object.

```
Class Dog: Animal   // child class inheriting parent class
{
    std::string sound;
    public:
        // now you can call getName and setName methods for Dog objects.
        void setSound(std::string s) { sound = s; }
        std::string getSound() { return sound; }
}
```

Usage:

```
Dog Askal;

Askal.setName("Bantay");
Askal.setSound("Woof");
```

Polymorphism allows the inherited method of a parent to change its behavior (code) according to its derived class. I leave this part for you to research since its not even required (yet) in your problem.

**Reply to your EDIT:**
Why not use "enum" to list down different planners and include it in your library. Then use a switch statement to search what particular planner the user is looking for then execute the corresponding function (or algorithm)

Comment: Voting down everyone without giving feedback. Great job

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12528010)

Comment: For your information, the original question was answered until the poster edited his question to explain the "actual problem".  It wasn't my lapse if the question was totally changed.